# Why won't my history.push code for Button onClick handler work?

Tags: reactjs, onclick, react-router-dom

I've only been working with React.js for a month or so and I hope someone can point me towards my errors so I can learn more.

I've created a reusable button component, but during testing, while the button displays correctly and I can change the value correctly - the `onClick` function is not working. Right now, I am trying to get the button to redirect `onClick` to the first path.

Below I have added the relevant areas of my code and hope someone can assist.

Display component:

```
import Sidebar from '../../Components/SideNav/Sidebar'
import GenButton from '../../Components/Buttons/GenButton'

export default function Sales({ authorized }) {

let history = useHistory(); 

const handleRoute = () =>{
    history.push("/")
}

if (!authorized) {
    return <Redirect to='/' />
}

return (
    <div>
        <Sidebar />
        <div className='content'>
            <h2>Sales Page</h2>
            <GenButton 
                value="Home"
                onClick={handleRoute}
            />
        
        </div>
    </div>
)
}
```

GenButton code:

```
import React from 'react'
import './GenButton.css';

const GenButton = ({value, onClick}) => {
return <button className='btn' onClick={() => onClick}>
{value}
</button>
```

}

```
export default GenButton
```

I need to understand more about why this isn't working, as multiple components I need to create will have between 2-4 buttons that need to route towards other pages or events.

Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because onClick is a function inside your Gen Button component you need to call it as a function.

```js
import React from 'react'
import './GenButton.css';

const GenButton = ({value, onClick = () => {}}) => {
return <button className='btn' onClick={() => onClick()}>
{value}
</button>
```

or just

```js
import React from 'react'
import './GenButton.css';

const GenButton = ({value, onClick = () => {}}) => {
return <button className='btn' onClick={onClick}>
{value}
</button>
```

I added a default value to onClick too incase there isn't one on a particular button.

Comment: Thank you very much for your assistance. It's greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Richard, yes, that did solve it. Thank you for checking!